# to solve a multiplication of two matrix

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, multiplication

How to multiply two matrices in python

```
input:

a=[[3 5]
   [5 6]]

b=[[7 6]
   [3 7]]
```

Expected Output:

```
ax =[[36 53]
     [65 72]]
```

Comment: assuming you use `numpy` (that would have been a helpful information in your question) i suggest [`matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html). and please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: What have you tested? We have nothing against a question about homework and to provides help about them. but we are not here to do your homework because it may be counterproductive to you because you won't learn if you haven't tried anything. IMO you should try something and ask a question when you are stuck. This way you will learn the most.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this. The one most suggest is to use numpy as described it will look like this

```
import numpy as np
a=[[3,5],
   [5,6]]

b=[[7,6],
   [3,7]]
print(np.matmul(a, b))
```

and returns

```
[[36 53]
[53 72]]
```

Now it is possible to with for loops, this WILL be slower than numpy but if we stick to plain old python it looks something like this.

```
result = [[0,0], [0,0]]

for i in range(len(a)):
   for j in range(len(b[0])):
       for k in range(len(b)):
           result[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j]

print(result)
```

and this returns

```
[[36, 53], [53, 72]]
```

So it's correct.